# Shellscript Array issue

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, sh

Based on my limited understanding on shell scripting, I have decided to use an array for easier sorting. However, whenever I call the function, it prints out multiple copies of the same book. For example,

**Inside BookDB.txt**

```
Title1:Author1:Price1:X1:Y1
Title2:Author2:Price2:X2:Y2
```

**Inside my terminal after calling either function**

```
Title1:Author1:Price1:X1:Y1
Title1:Author1:Price1:X1:Y1
Title1:Author1:Price1:X1:Y1
Title2:Author2:Price2:X2:Y2
Title2:Author2:Price2:X2:Y2
Title2:Author2:Price2:X2:Y2
```

What have I done wrong here? It keeps printing out multiple "instances" of it and occasionally would then save on my text file resulting in my text file containing multiple "instances" as well (I have yet to confirm what causes it as it sometimes occur only).

I have attached the main portions of the function codes. `$FILENAME`'s value is *./BookDB.txt*. Thank you in advance for your expertise and help.

**Function inventory_summary_report()**

```
inventory_summary_report()
{
access_bookdb_data
echo "--------------------------------------------"
echo "<INVENTORY SUMMARY REPORT>"   
echo ""

printf "%-35s\t%-15s\t%-10s\t%-5s\t%-5s\t%-10s\n" \
   "Title" "Author" "Price" "Qty Avail" "Qty Sold" "Total Sales"
echo ""

#Prints all data from database
for ((i=0; $i<${#TITLE[@]}; i++)); do
    printf "%-35s\t%-15s\t$%-0.2f\t\t%-3d\t\t%-3d\t\t$%-0.2f\n" \
           "${TITLE[$i]}" "${AUTHOR[$i]}" "${PRICE[$i]}" "${AVAIL[$i]}" \ 
           "${SOLD[$i]}" "$(echo ${PRICE[$i]}*${SOLD[$i]} | bc)"
done

echo "--------------------------------------------"
}
```

**Function report_books_statistics()**

```
report_books_statistics()
{
access_bookdb_data
echo "--------------------------------------------"
echo "<BOOK STATISTICS REPORT>"
echo ""

tempSoldArr=("${SOLD[@]}");
tempTitleArr=("${TITLE[@]}");
tempAuthorArr=("${AUTHOR[@]}");
tempAvailArr=("${AVAIL[@]}");

#Sorts numbers in descending array
for ((last=numRec-1; last>0; last--)); do
    for ((i=0; i<last; i++)); do
        j=$((i+1))
        if [ ${tempSoldArr[i]} - lt ${tempSoldArr[j]} ]; then
            tempS=${tempSoldArr[$i]}
            tempSoldArr[$i]=${tempSoldArr[$j]}
            tempSoldArr[$j]=$tempS
            tempT=${tempTitleArr[$i]}
            tempTitleArr[$i]=${tempTitleArr[$j]}
            tempTitleArr[$j]=$tempT
            tempA=${tempAuthorArr[$i]}
            tempAuthorArr[$i]=${tempAuthorArr[$j]}
            tempAuthorArr[$j]=$tempA
            tempAvail=${tempAvailArr[$i]}
            tempAvailArr[$i]=${tempAvailArr[$j]}
            tempAvailArr[$j]=$tempAvail
        fi
    done
done

#Shows most popular books
echo "The Top 5 Books Sold are"
echo "--------------------------------------------"
printf "%-35s\t%-15s\t%-5s\n" "Title" "Author" "Qty Sold"
echo ""

#Descending order
for ((i=0; i<5; i++)); do
printf "%-35s\t%-15s\t%-5s\n" "${tempTitleArr[$i]}" "${tempAuthorArr[$i]}" "${tempSoldArr[i]}"  
done

echo ""
echo ""

#Least popular books
echo "The Least 5 Books Sold are"
echo "--------------------------------------------"
printf "%-35s\t%-15s\t%-5s\n" "Title" "Author" "Qty Sold"
echo ""

#Ascending order
for ((i=numRec-1; i>numRec-5; i--)); do
    printf "%-35s\t%-15s\t%-5s\n" "${tempTitleArr[$i]}" "${tempAuthorArr[$i]}" "${tempSoldArr[i]}"  
done

echo ""
echo ""

#Books with <20 quantity available
echo "Books with quantity available lesser than 20"
echo "--------------------------------------------"
printf "%-35s\t%-15s\t%-5s\n" "Title" "Author" "Qty Left"
echo ""

for ((i=0; i<numRec; i++)); do
    if [[ ${tempAvailArr[i]} -lt 21 ]]; then
        printf "%-35s\t%-15s\t%-5s\n" "${tempTitleArr[$i]}" \
               "${tempAuthorArr[$i]}" "${tempAvailArr[i]}"
    fi
done

echo "--------------------------------------------"
}
```

**Function access_bookdb_data()**

```
access_bookdb_data()
{
#Creates BookDB.txt if it does not exist
if ! [ -f $FILENAME ] ; then
    touch $FILENAME
fi

#Sort file and replace it
sort $FILENAME -o $FILENAME

#Reads sorted data and store into array
while IFS=':' read -a LINE; do
    TITLE[$COUNT]=${LINE[0]};
    AUTHOR[$COUNT]=${LINE[1]};
    PRICE[$COUNT]=${LINE[2]};
    AVAIL[$COUNT]=${LINE[3]};
    SOLD[$COUNT]=${LINE[4]};
    let COUNT++;
done<$FILENAME
}
```

Comment: TLDR; Is there a question here? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @sjsam My terminal output prints multiple instances of a particular line in my text file. That is the problem that I am trying to fix.

Comment: Ugh! Have a look at http://shellcheck.net Always double-quote variables, e.g. `"$FILENAME"`. Don't use all upper case variables, they are reserved by the shell for the shell. Also, don't sort in place. e.g `sort X -o X`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell `sort X -o X` is designed precisely to allow "in-place" sorting; it is quite different from `sort X > X`.

Comment: @chepner Thank you for the correction - I shall try and keep up!